# NumPy, SciPy - how to calculate the z score for subsets of an array?

Tags: numpy, scipy

Using the array `a` below as an example, I am looking for a scalable way to calculate the [z score](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) of the last 2 columns `a[:, 3:]` separately for each value in the third column `a[:,2]`

```
In [52]: import numpy as np; from scipy import stats

In [53]: a = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 1., 2.], [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  4.], [ 1.,  0.,
    ...:   0.,  5.,  6.], [1.,  0.,  1.,  7.,  8.], [ 2.,  0., 0.,  9.,  6.], [2.,
    ...:   0.,  1.,  8.,  9.], [ 3.,  np.NaN,  np.NaN,  np.NaN,  np.NaN]])

In [54]: a
Out[54]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  7.,  8.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  6.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  1.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 3., nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

For the case where the third column is 0 `a[:,2] == 0`, I can calculate it with

```
In [48]: np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 0][:,3:]), (1, 1))
Out[48]:
array([[-1.22474487, -1.41421356],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.22474487,  0.70710678]])
```

and for the case where the third column is 1 `a[:,2] == 1`, I can calculate it with

```
In [49]: np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 1][:,3:]), (1, 1))
Out[49]:
array([[-1.38873015, -1.38873015],
       [ 0.46291005,  0.46291005],
       [ 0.9258201 ,  0.9258201 ]])
```

How can I augment my original array with these results, regardless of the number of rows and values in the third column, to create something like the following -

```
Out[62]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,
        -1.22474487, -1.41421356],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,
        -1.38873015, -1.38873015],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  5.        ,  6.        ,
         0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  7.        ,  8.        ,
         0.46291005,  0.46291005],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  9.        ,  6.        ,
         1.22474487,  0.70710678],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  8.        ,  9.        ,
         0.9258201 ,  0.9258201 ],
       [ 3.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an array with same number of columns as `a` and use `np.column_stack` to combine them

```
z1 = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 0][:,3:]), (1, 1))
z2 = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 1][:,3:]), (1, 1))
z=np.zeros((a.shape[0],z1.shape[1]))*np.nan
z[::2][:z1.shape[0]]=z1
z[1::2][:z2.shape[0]]=z2
arr1 = np.column_stack((a,z))
arr1
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,
        -1.22474487, -1.41421356],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,
        -1.38873015, -1.38873015],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  5.        ,  6.        ,
         0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  7.        ,  8.        ,
         0.46291005,  0.46291005],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  9.        ,  6.        ,
         1.22474487,  0.70710678],
       [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  8.        ,  9.        ,
         0.9258201 ,  0.9258201 ],
       [ 3.        ,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
                nan,         nan]])
```

for `n` unique values in `a[:,2]`

```
N = np.unique(a[:,2])[~np.isnan(np.unique(a[:,2]))]
zTemp = [np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == k][:,3:]), (1, 1)) for k in N]
z=np.zeros((a.shape[0], zTemp[0].shape[1]))*np.nan
for i in range(len(zTemp)):
    z[i::2][:z1.shape[0]]=zTemp[i]
arr1 = np.column_stack((a,z))
```

Comment: I agree that stacking the columns works in this particular simple case, but I am looking for a more general and scalable solution. For example when the source array has a large number or rows and different values in third column. It would inefficient to individually calculate `zN = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == N][:,3:]), (1, 1))` when `N` is large and stack them together

Comment: Your edited answer is correct, thanks. My z score statement `np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 1][:,3:]), (1, 1))` was unnecessarily verbose, effectively the same as `stats.zscore(a[a[:,2] == 1][:,3:])`